# Get item id from news record in detail view tx_news

Tags: php, typo3, tx-news

i want to use a news record id to get some data from a table.

The background: 
I have extends tx_news with one new field in tca. The data will be saved into the correct database table - but i can't get this content in a viewhelper. To resolve this problem, i want to use the record id from the current news entry to make a mysql call.

But i don't know from where come this id.

For example: newsItem.Id doesn't functional.

Answer (score 2):

The ID from the News is available in Fluid: `{newsItem.uid}`.

But I would suggest to use the "official" way to extend EXT:news instead of using a complicated hack. You can extend EXT:news easily, see the [official documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/latest/Main/Tutorial/ExtendingNews/Index.html#extend-the-database-table).

All you have to do is create a little extension (it could also be your template extension), add the TCA configuration for the field, then add a custom model and tell EXT:news about your model by placing a special text file in your extension.